# Unable to connect to remote JMX using VisualVM but OK with JConsole

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm, jconsole

I'm attempting to connect to a remote JMX service using VisualVM 1.3.8 with JRE 1.8.0.  Making exactly the same connection with JConsole works perfectly, however the attempt to use the same parameters with VVM just hangs at the 'Adding services' stage.  I've looked in the VVM log but there is literally nothing logged.

I also read [here](https://visualvm.java.net/applications_remote.html) at the VVM remote JMX doc:

> Note: To retrieve and display information on applications running on the remote host, the jstatd utility needs to be running on the remote host.

That puzzles me since I can make the remote JMX connection using JConsole and as far as I can tell, jstatd is not running on the remote.

Does anyone know if jstatd a requirement *only for VVM* as a remote JMX client?  As the JMX connection can be made with JConsole between the same client and server endpoints, then there's no problem with network/firewall etc.

Other than that I'm really puzzled where else to look for clues?

Comment: I have just tried the same test using jvisualvm from the bin folder of the JDK 8 distribution and the JMX connection works perfectly there too.  Does anyone know what the difference is between VisualVM as distributed by [java.net](https://visualvm.java.net/) and Oracle's JDK?  java.net says: 

"JDK 8 has been released and is available for  download here. It contains Java VisualVM tool based on VisualVM 1.3.6."

so perhaps my problem is related to the version of VVM?

Comment: when connecting locally the attach api can be used which uses the file system (under Linux) without needing network access.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble when I switched from Java 7 to 8, while using SOCKS where I was updating proxy settings through `VisualVM -> Tools -> Plugins -> Settings -> Proxy Settings`. However, I have been successful with the following:

1. Run your JVM with the following options:

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<JMX_PORT> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

Note that you could obviously do something more secure, both w.r.t SSL and authentication.

2. Setup a SOCKS proxy from your localhost to the remote server:

`ssh -D<SOCKS_PORT> -vvv -N <REMOTE_HOST>`

3. Run either of these commands on your localhost:

`jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=<SOCKS_PORT> service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<REMOTE_HOST:JMX_PORT>/jmxrmi
jvisualvm -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=<SOCKS_PORT> --openjmx <REMOTE_HOST>`

Comment: In case anyone wonders regarding tomcat , these lines should go in setenv.sh